# Items in a List not ordering correctly on screen when filtering in Blazor

Tags: blazor

I'm developping a photo gallery where clients can select their favorite pictures, order photos... There is a page where users select the photo album they want to access. The albums are presented in masonry style form and they can filter them by name typing in a search field. When filtering everything goes fine. The unwanted albums start to disappear and the order is correct. But if I delete some of the characters typed the albums appear in a quite extrange order. I've tried `OrderBy()` but the result es the same.

This is the code. `class="bricklayer"` is just for the javascript library I use for the items to present in a masonry style. If I remove it, it does not affect the order. `CadenaBusqueda` is the search string.

```
<div class="bricklayer">

            @foreach (var album in Albumes
     .Where(x => x.AlbumReducido.NombreAlbum.ToLowerInvariant()
                  .Contains(CadenaBusqueda.ToLowerInvariant()))
     .OrderBy(al => al.AlbumReducido.NombreAlbum))
            {

                <div class="tarjeta text-center" style="width:95%" @onclick="(async () => await SeleccionarAlbum(album.AlbumReducido.ID))">
                    <div class="text-dark w-75">
                        @album.AlbumReducido.NombreAlbum
                    </div>
                    <img class="img-fluid"  style="border-bottom-left-radius:1vh; border-bottom-right-radius:1vh;" src="@album.RutaThumbnail" />
                </div>
            }
            @{ Terminado = true;}
        </div>
```

Thanks in advance.
Edit 2: This is the code for the moment where I have included your suggestions (I really appreciate).Results are exactly the same.

```
<div class="bricklayer">

            @foreach (var album in Albumes
                .Where(x => x.AlbumReducido.NombreAlbum.ToLowerInvariant().
                Contains(CadenaBusqueda.ToLowerInvariant())).
                ToList().OrderBy(al => al.AlbumReducido.NombreAlbum))
            {

                <div @key="album.GetHashCode()" class="tarjeta text-center" style="width:95%" @onclick="(async () => await SeleccionarAlbum(album.AlbumReducido.ID))">
                    <div class="text-dark w-75">
                        @album.AlbumReducido.NombreAlbum
                    </div>
                    <img class="img-fluid"  style="border-bottom-left-radius:1vh; border-bottom-right-radius:1vh;" src="@album.RutaThumbnail" />
                </div>
            }
            @{ Terminado = true;}
        </div>
```

Edit: I add some screenshots:

This is part of the list without any filtering:

[image]

When I start to filter, everything is fine:

[image]

But when I start to clear or completely clear the search field, it comes up in a extrange order:

[image]

Comment: This code looks Ok, how do you change the searchtext (CadenaBusqueda)?

Comment: My bet is that this is another Entity Framework bug... Please, try to materialize the query (call .ToList()) before the OrderBy(...) and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks @Vi100. Just tried calling `.ToList()` with the same result. Here @HenkHolterman is where I change the searchtext: `<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Nombre del álbum" @bind-value="CadenaBusqueda" @bind-value:event="oninput" />`

Comment: @V100 still has a point - is your `Albums` an IQueryable?  The ToList should be where you assign Albums, not in the foreach.

Comment: @Henk Holterman `Albums` is a `List<>`  itself. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but it should have 'just worked'. Create a [mcve] if you still need help.

Comment: @Henk Holterman, thanks again. In fact, I still need help. For the moment, I just forgot it and continued working on the rest. I will tray to maje a minimal reproducible example ASAP.